# CLI: How to browse contents in a jar file?

Tags: java, zip, jar

Inside a Ubuntu OS, how can I browse contents in a jar file by terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the command `unzip -l [filename]` to list the contents of the jar archive file.

First, you might need to install unzip:
`sudo apt install unzip`

Example of unzip usage on the file gettext.jar:

```
username@ubuntu-server:~$ unzip -l /usr/share/java/gettext.jar
Archive:  /usr/share/java/gettext.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2019-03-06 23:31   META-INF/
       66  2019-03-06 23:31   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     5657  2019-03-06 23:31   gnu/gettext/DumpResource.class
      699  2019-03-06 23:31   gnu/gettext/GetURL$1.class
     1579  2019-03-06 23:31   gnu/gettext/GetURL.class
---------                     -------
     8001                     5 files
```

Alternatively, you could use the Java JDK's jar command to view the contents of a jar file: `jar -tf [filename]`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320510/viewing-contents-of-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

[Official information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html):

> The basic format of the command for viewing the contents of a JAR file
> is:
>
> ```
> jar tf jar-file
> ```
>
> The JAR tool will display additional information if you use the v
> option:
>
> ```
> jar tvf TicTacToe.jar
> ```

If you don't have it, you should install `jar` with

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
```